# Using GEB, how can I very text and click OK in an alert box

Tags: webdriver, geb

I have a basic alert box with OK or Cancel options

[image]

Using selenium, it was easy to use `alert.getText()` and `alert.accept`. How can I handle this same scenario using GEB?

It looks like I can verify the text using withConfirm, but I can't figure out how to click the OK button.

```java
assert withConfirm(true) { $("input", name: "showConfirm").click() } == "Do you like Geb?"
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Your code does click the OK button.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown us should work, you have copied it straight from the Geb manual.

The assertion will check the text in a pop up following a click action on a html element.  In the case below (the code you pasted) when an html element with the name "showConfirm" is clicked, assert that a pop up is displayed with the text "Do you like Geb?".

```
assert withConfirm(true) { $("input", name: "showConfirm").click() } == "Do you like Geb?"
```

So you need to change the code to relate to whatever element action causes your pop up to appear:

```
assert withConfirm(true) { $("input", name: "thisIsTheNameOfMyElementThatWillCauseAPopUpToAppear").click() } == "Are you sure?"
```

Note that the Geb AlertAndConfirmSupport class that deals with alert and confirm dialog methods should actually prevent the popup from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the ...(true) part.

`withConfirm(`**true**`) { performSomeAction} == "Some expected text"` is loosely equivalent to -

```
performSomeAction
getAlert().text() == "Some expected text"
getAlert().accept()
```

And on the other side of the coin `withConfirm(`**false**`) { performSomeAction} == "Some expected text"` is loosely equivalent to -

```
performSomeAction
getAlert().text() == "Some expected text"
getAlert().dismiss()
```

I say loosely equivalent here because as mentioned by @Rushby Geb deals with withConfirm blocks by intercepting the alert and not displaying it.